# Django Error - TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder: '['userType']' from '['userType']'

Tags: python, html, django

```
 {% if 'is_logged_in' in request.session %} {% if request.session['userType'] == 0 %} {% include 'headersuccess.html' %} {% else %}dfgh {% endif %}
```

This is my code. I am checking two conditions But I am getting the above error . Can anybody please help me to solve the same?

My views.py is

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if('is_logged_in' in request.session):
        id = request.session['authToken'];
        return render(request,"index.html",{'uid':id});
    else:
        return render(request,"index.html",{});
```

views.py(server)

This is my server code and in request.session userType is present

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_user(request):
    user = None
    try:
        #user = models.user.objects.get(Q(user_name=request.POST['key'])|Q(contact__email=request.POST['key']))#|Q(contact__phone=request.POST['key']))
        user = models.user.objects.get(Q(user_name=request.POST['key'])|Q(email=request.POST['key']))#|Q(contact__phone=request.POST['key']))

        pswd = pass_enc(request.POST['password'],user.token)

        if user.password == pswd:

            #create signed auth token
            data = {
                'uid' : user.uid,
                'userType' : user.userType,
                'is_agent' : user.is_agent,
                'is_new'   : user.is_new,
                'is_admin' : user.userType == 8,
                'created_at':time.time()
            }

            signedToken = create_crypt_header(data)

            session = None

            try:
                session = models.session.objects.get(user=user)
                session.activeSession += 1
                session.save()
            except Exception as e:
                session = models.session(
                    user=user,
                    activeSession=1
                )
                session.save()
            #handel weblogin

            ajax_token = create_crypt_header({'val':1,'at':time.time()})

            request.session['authToken'] = signedToken
            request.session['v'] = 1
            request.session['ajax_token'] = ajax_token
            request.session['is_logged_in'] = True

            return JsonResponse({'authentication' : True,'authToken':signedToken,"userType":user.userType,'session_mask':session.sessionId,'is_new':user.is_new})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'authentication' : False})

    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'authentication': False})
```

This is my code. I am checking two conditions But I am getting the above error . Can anybody please help me to solve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Inside template to access dict's element by key use `.`: `request.session.userType`.

Also you dont need two if use one instead: `{% if 'is_logged_in' in request.session and request.session.userType == 0 %}`. In case you have two `if` blocks in your code you need to add two `{% endif %}` statements.

Comment: when I try this way.. if condition is not working sir

Comment: also maybe point out that the OP has 2 if statements and just 1 endif.

Comment: @med I dont see where you add `userType` to the session. Yoy should add: `request.session['userType'] = user.userType` to login_user view.